Face recognition passing while 2 different people
I've been experimenting with the face_recognition library in Python. This is great since it's very easy to implement, however now that I'm working with it I am running into an issue.
I followed the explanation and examples from the repository, however when using the compare_faces function I get True while the person in the frame is totally different from the existing face_encodings in my codebase.
I have tried changing the tolerance parameter in the compare_faces function and also change the face_encodings model parameter to large . This however has not made benefits as lowering the tolerance causes another issue, meaning that more face_encodings are added to the system for the same person.
import face_recognition

known_face_encodings = []

# Frame is from OpenCV
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, face_locations, model="small")  

for face_encoding in face_encodings:
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(
        known_face_encodings, face_encoding, tolerance=0.6)

    if True in matches:
        print(matches) # [True, False, etc.]        
    else:
        # Append new face to known_face_encodings
        known_face_encodings.append(face_encoding)

The expect result for person 1 would be to result in [True, False]. However this sometimes yields [True, True] or even False resulting in another item in the known_face_encodings array.
Has anyone experienced this issue before, and if so how did you go about solving this?

I've just found that preprocessing is required to go from OpenCV to face_recognition using frame[:, :, ::-1]. This does result in a error as follows: Exception inside application: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
